# html syntax highlight for vscode python notebooks

Tags: python, html, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

as a data scientist and a former frontend developer, I sometimes use HTML with IPython to present data with some html components in ***VScode notebooks*** for better visualizations.

```py
my_html_string = f"""
<div style="height: 100px;">
  <h1>Some HTML {b} </h1>
</div>
"""
```

but usualy I write html in multi line python string so I dont have syntax highlighting. which is very frustrating for complex UI. is there some plugin for VScode for multiline string html syntax highlighting ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use escape string instead of using plugin, that's how I do it

Comment: a small example would be nice

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).